# $P$ representation of a general Gaussian state

Tags: quantum-optics, phase-space

Let $\rho$ be the density operator of a Gaussian quantum state on $M$ modes. This implies that its Wigner function can be written as
$$ W_{\text{Gaussian}}\left(\boldsymbol{q},\boldsymbol{p}\right)=\frac{1}{\pi^{N}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det\left(\sigma\right)}}e^{-\left(\boldsymbol{X}-\boldsymbol{d}\right)^{T}\sigma^{-1}\left(\boldsymbol{X}-\boldsymbol{d}\right)}$$
where $\boldsymbol{X}=(\boldsymbol{q}, \boldsymbol{p})$. Clearly, Gaussian states are fully determined by the covariance matrix $\sigma$ and the displacement vector $\boldsymbol{d}$.

Question: Is there a formula for the $P$ representation of such a state $\rho$ in terms of $\sigma$ and $\boldsymbol{d}$?

I know that the Husimi Q function of a Gaussian state is also a Gaussian, on the other hand, the $P$ function cannot just be a Gaussian since entangled states lead to negativity in the $P$ function.

**Edit:** Starting a solution: The $P$-function can be obtained from its characteristic function as a Fourier transform (let's start with one mode only for simplicity)
$$P(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\pi^2} \int d^2 \lambda \; e^{\lambda^{*}\alpha-\lambda \alpha^{*}} \chi_P(\lambda)$$
and furthermore $\chi_P(\lambda) = \chi_W (\lambda) e^{\frac{1}{2} |\lambda|^2}$ where $\chi_W(\lambda)$ is the characteristic function corresponding to the Wigner function of the state. Hence, 
$$P(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\pi^2} \int d^2 \lambda \; e^{\frac{1}{2} |\lambda|^2}e^{\lambda^{*}\alpha-\lambda \alpha^{*}} \int d^2\beta \; W(\beta)  e^{\lambda\beta^{*}-\lambda^{*} \beta}$$

However, if I try integrating out $\lambda$ now, the integral does not converge if I am not mistaken. So to summarize, I have trouble inverting the known Weierstrass transform
$$W(\alpha,\alpha^*)= \frac{2}{\pi} \int P(\beta,\beta^*) e^{-2|\alpha-\beta|^2} \, d^2\beta$$ given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprobability_distribution#Characteristic_functions).

Comment: You invert the [standard conversion Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprobability_distribution#Characteristic_functions).  The Wigner function you start with  is positive semidefinite too --basically the only Wiggie that is such. Flesh out your unstated "knowledge" of  dramatically novel   properties of the *P* function.

Comment: Thank you, however, precisely the inversion is what troubles me. I put some of my thought process above. Based on that, maybe you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I am not experienced with antinormal orderings and hence *P* -functions, but you get $\delta$-functions for them, routinely. In any case, W. Schleich, *Quantum Optics in Phase Space*, Sec. 12.3.2 and 12.4, (especially p 343 where he does the squeezed state for P) and appendices beats the subject to a pulp. I'm not sure working out convolutions would help you. Try the simplest phase space, one p, one q, first.

Comment: Stick a delta function for P in your very last formula and observe the corresponding Gaussian W.